# Is it acceptable to use "to be" to describe possession?

Tags: verbs, objects, be

I recently was explaining a couple of Marathi phrases to my friend, and I realized that the language doesn't have the word "to have". We have multiple different ways of expressing posession, but I found a particular one rather interesting: When I want to say "I have a pen", I instead say "My pen is" (literally translated).

The moment I translated it, I realized that this construct was pretty interesting. The verb "to be" is rarely seen without any object — if at all. The phrase "My <something> is" in English sounds a bit poetic to me. I've never heard it being used myself, but it may be something that's fallen into disuse.

My question is, is this a valid<sup>1</sup> way of expressing possession? Is it OK to use "My pen is" in place of "I have a pen"?

A more general question<sup>2</sup>  is: When is it acceptable to use the verb "to be" without any object?

<sup>1. Poetic license aside</sup>

<sup>2. Which may be too broad, so this is a bonus question :)</sup>

Comment: From my personal experience, I would think "My pen is" would be a poetic way of expressing "My pen exists" not "I have a pen", in English.

Comment: @called2voyage Mine too. Of course, "My pen exists" implies that I have a pen in the first place.

Comment: True, but I don't think that meaning is immediately apparent to an English speaker.

Comment: @called2voyage I know. In everyday use I'd get looked at funny for using it. But there are many such constructs that are considered correct usage but are confusing to the general audience.

Comment: Why should not 'it is my pen' work in the sense of 'I have a pen'? I don't see any problem, +1.

Comment: I think this is Off Topic General Reference for ELU, but it would have been okay on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Whose standards of validity would you like to use for "correct usage"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, I personally don't consider myself an ELL (of course, I learn new things every day, but I'm not actively learning) -- IMO I'm reasonably proficient in the language and this seems to be something that one doesn't come across every day. Or any day.

Comment: @AtsutoNagatomo "It is my pen" is slightly different (as it is corect usage even though it may not mean "I have a pen"). The question is, is "My pen is" correct usage of the verb? Or must it have an object?

Comment: @called2voyage Hmm. Good question, I can't immediately think of any benchmark for correct usage (examples?), but if anyone has an answer, they could mention the benchmark.

Comment: *I think, therefore I am.*

Comment: I think you should have al least three suspension points (...) as object in this case, 'My pen is ...' :)

Comment: @bib Of course, that's the literal translation of the corresponding Latin statement, so that may not be valid English. But yeah, it's a similar type of statement.

Comment: @bib, I don't see how 'cogito, ergo sum' implies possession but the case of 'evil possession' :)

Comment: @ Manishearth: *Please* don't take my comment/closevote as personal criticism. But the fact of the matter is native speakers never use *to be* in any way that implies "possession". And apart from contrived contexts like the Cartesian *"I think therefore I am"*, or "cut-down" refutations *("He's not coming" - "Yes, he **is**")*, we simply don't use "to be" in the way you're suggesting. Poetically or otherwise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not, but I do know that this isn't used in everyday English by native speakers. As mentioned, it could be valid English that's fallen into disuse. That's what I was curious about.

Comment: @ Manishearth: I could be wrong, but I think it's highly unlikely *to be* ever had any connotations of "possession" in English. And I doubt it was ever used to mean *to **exist*** except in pithy translations such as *Cogito, ergo sum = I think, therefore I am* and  *Que sera, sera = Whatever will be, will be*. I stand by my closevote, and I really do think you'd get a better understanding of *why* this particular auxiliary "helper" verb works the way it does by asking on ELL.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And that's a valid answer. I know how the verb works _nrmally_, I was wondering if it could be used this way, that's all.

Comment: While this type of construction does not exist in English, ‘to have’ is a very common verb to be lacking, cross-linguistically. I saw a number once (whether it was trustworthy or not, I do not know) state that about 70 per cent of the world’s languages have no such lexeme as ‘to have’. Some languages do as Marathi, others say ‘mine is the X’ (like Russian, I believe?), yet others (like Irish and, optionally, Latin) say ‘for/to/at me is X’. Latin is the only example I know of of a language that actually has a common ‘to have’ verb, but still uses the periphrastic construction, too.

Comment: @Janus: I ***have*** the impression most usages of *to have* and *to be* ***are*** distantly (if at all) related to the meanings *to possess* and *to exist*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a hypothetical construction rather than practical English usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:
No.

LONG ANSWER:
A grammatical *Object* is a noun (phrase) which “receives the action” of a verb: either a Direct Object (which undergoes the action) or an Indirect Object (which receives the Direct Object or benefits from the action).

The verb *BE*, however, does not take *objects* of either sort. It is not an ordinary verb, expressing an action or event but a *copula*, asserting a relationship between two arguments, a Subject and a Complement.

Ordinarily both arguments are required.* Consequently, *My pen is* is not a grammatical sentence. If you wish to assert ownership of the pen, you must say something along the lines of

> The pen is mine. *or* 
>   This is my pen.

---

* There are two exceptions: 1) In imperatives (*Be bloody, bold and resolute!*) the subject is omitted because it is defined by the form itself to be the person you are addressing. 2) If you are willing to appear fervidly rhetorical, you may employ *BE* to mean *EXIST* in statements like *My pen **is***, with heavy emphasis on ***is*** to indicate that you are using it in an unconventional way. But  this means something else: it does not assert that the pen is yours, but that the pen in question, which happens to be yours, actually exists.

Comment: Mine the pen is.

Comment: @KitFox Yoda you be?

Comment: +1 for actually mentioning that ‘to be’ does not take objects.

Comment: I still think this should have been asked on ELL, but it's a fine answer (or *pair* of answers - both the short and the long version are spot on! :).

Comment: Ah, so the exception only comes in the imperative. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In fact the word "have" connotes custody, not ownership.  "My" connotes ownership.  So the two statements

- I have the pen.
- The pen is mine.

...are not equivalent.  It might be my pen, but you have it.  Give it back!  If I say "I have a pen" there might be an implication that it is my pen, but it might be yours and it is merely in my custody or possession.

As to "When is it acceptable to use the verb 'to be' without any object?"  "To be" is intransitive, so [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb) it cannot take an object.  Therefore, the answer is "never".

Answer (score 3):

Saying "I have a pen" connotes possession - the verb [*have*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have) here is used as a [main verb](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/verbtohave.html) showing the action that the subject  *I* performs on the object *pen*.

*My pen is ...* implies that the pen is already yours - possession is implicit in the determiner [*my*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/my).

Of course, poetic license totally allows such usage, I don't think it would be considered acceptable to say "My pen is!" without trying to infer that, somehow, your pen has acquired life. :)

Comment: Makes sense. Your upvote is!

Comment: My pen is, however, alive.  It tells me things.  It makes me do things.  Fear the pen, for it is mightier than the sword!

Comment: @Cyberherbalist That's awesome! I still wouldn't bring a pen to a sword fight. :-P

Comment: Me neither, truth be told.  I may be crazy but I am definitely not insane.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist New question: What's the difference between crazy and insane? I was just wondering.

Comment: Don't take this as a clinical assessment or definition, but to me, being crazy is to do irrational things as a matter of will, being completely aware of and perhaps even exultant in the craziness.  Insanity is irrationality that cannot perceive the irrationality, not as a matter of will, but as a matter of compulsion that cannot be controlled by will.  By this definition, for example, a test-pilot is crazy, but probably not insane.  On the other hand, a person afflicted with paranoia cannot see the paranoia, and to him or her it is not irrational, and cannot will it otherwise; this is insanity